# Where can I find out what each JDK version's lowest compatible JRE version is?

Tags: java

I've searched all over and can't find a reference that just plainly states what the minimum JREs are for each JDK. I thought this would be easily accessible information.

For example, let's say I know I have to have code that can be run on a 1.7 JRE. But I want to play with newer features, not being stuck in the old JDK 7 ways of doing things. So, I want to see if I can use 8, 9, 10... in my source code and set the "java -target" to 1.7.

Comment: @Jens That's not true. Please undo the downvote. 1.7 has forward incompatibility

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to find out is to let `javac` tell you.

If you give an incompatible source/target version, you'll be informed with

`javac: source release 1.X requires target release 1.Y`.

If you're targetting `1.7`, you're stuck with `1.7` source as well, since

```
javac -source 1.8 -target 1.7 Foo.java
javac: source release 1.8 requires target release 1.8
```